# Unity Application Block - Constructor injection in configuration file

Tags: c#, constructor, unity-container, constructor-injection

How can I specify that constructor with no parameter should be used while creating the object? I know how to do it for the parameterized one but cannot find any help for the parameter less constructor.

I know how to do this through code but need solution for doing it through configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you just specify an empty `constructor` node in the config?

```
<types>
    <type type="MyProject.IRepository, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"
          mapTo="MyProject.DefaultRepository, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
        <lifetime type="transient" />
        <typeConfig>
            <constructor>
            </constructor>
        </typeConfig>
    </type>
</types>
```

Comment: Sure it works.
I had had it already. It was some other piece of code messing up things.